# Flask project works in local environment, throws weird error on heroku about missing files (that are dynamically added anyway!)

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, flask

I'm developing a flask application for image editing and up until a couple commits, it's been working great on both my local environment and heroku. I commited a tiny change and now I'm seeing a weird error. Yes, rolling back fixes the error but based on the change I made, I can't explain why heroku would be giving me trouble.

The app pulls images from an api and stores them in a tmp directory on the server* where edits are made to the image. The tmp directory is part of the git repo and the images should be pulled from the api every time the page loads. The error I'm getting on heroku now is:

```
File "/app/app/views.py", line 71, in edit_result 
Jan 17 22:05:23 *** app/web.1:      i.save('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_FOLDER, filename)) 
Jan 17 22:05:23 *** app/web.1:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1459, in save 
Jan 17 22:05:23 *** app/web.1:      fp = builtins.open(fp, "wb") 
Jan 17 22:05:23 *** app/web.1:  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/app/tmp/5cfae63a182ff935fe0fb142_640.jpg'
```

The relevant lines in my views file are:

```
@app.route('/edit/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_result():
        url = request.args.get('url')
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]

        i = Image.open(StringIO(requests.get(url).content))
        i.save('%s/%s' % (MEDIA_FOLDER, filename))

        return render_template("edit.html",
            image_filename=filename,
        )
```

Looking at the working git commit vs the next one that *broke* things, this is all that was commited:
`<option value="Default">Choose Font</option>` was added to a Jinja2 template, `@cache.cached(timeout=50)` was removed from a view and `"Default": "/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf",` was added to a dictionary

A couple more notes:

- I tried to pull up the image listed in the error message and it
  actually does come up on the heroku instance.
- I thought maybe I was
  confusing the commits and looked over the last few prior to the one I
  thought was the working commit, and the next few following the broken
  commit. I can't see anything that would cause just heroku to fail,
  not my local environment.
- I, probably stupidly, continued working on the app on my local environment. I hadn't finished coding logging into the app so I was just getting error 500 on heroku and thought it was a fluke. I'm a dozen commits ahead of the heroku deploy now and a lot has changed including those commits that *broke* things being removed entirely for a better user experience.
- Things are still working perfectly, locally.
- Permissions haven't changed on the tmp directory

I'm new to heroku, this is my first app deployed there. Maybe I'm missing something which is why I'm coming to you! Any advice would be appreciated.

*I know heroku doesn't want things like this stored locally and I'm in the process of rewriting the views to use S3 instead...

Comment: Heroku dynos are ephemeral. Eventually they will disappear and be replaced by new ones. They also do not share a file system. That means that any files saved inside a dyno's file system will only be available to that specific dyno and will be lost when it turns off.

Comment: Right, I understand that. That's why these images are pulled into the system every time that specific page loads. The tmp directory is part of the git repo so it should stick though. The app is generating the files so they shouldn't ever come up as missing.

Comment: @dirn your comment made me think twice about my git repo. I added a condition to my views to check for the tmp directory and create it if it didn't exist which was exactly the case, the tmp folder may have been included in earlier commits but I removed it several back and the heroku dyno must have coincidentally cleared at the commit mentioned above causing me to think that was the problematic commit. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about my answer in the comment left by dirn on the first post but essentially my directory was NOT included in my git repo as I thought, so it wasn't on the heroku dyno after it cleared. I added a condition in my views.py to check for the directory and create it if it doesn't exist which fixed the problem:

```
if not os.path.exists(MEDIA_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(MEDIA_FOLDER)
```